# Dynamically choosing a class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

First I am not sure how to call my question, so any suggestion for better title please let me know.

I want to create an interface so that other people can add their implementations, and then at runtime decide which of the implementations to use.

i.e.
I create an interface "Food" and there exist 2 implementations "Breakfast" and "Lunch". In the implementation both have the same method names and same arguments, and I want to let the user at runtime call either of them. "makeFood() using Breakfast" or "makeFood() using Lunch".

One possibility is to only compile one implementation, but this will require to delete .class files if the other implementation has to be use in the future.

Or should I be using some type of inheritance?

Additionally (not priority):
I wouldnt know the implementation class names, so someone could create "dinner" or "secondBreakfast". Which would lead me to another dilemma, what to do if user requests a "class" that is not implemented yet :S I can always assume the user will know which implementations are available.

Comment: use `factory` strategy, return different `Food` instance according to the passed in parameters,

Comment: Do you have the implementations already an only want the user to choose which one to use, or do you want the user to add it's own library at runtime?

Comment: @Juan, if user pass in an invalid parameters, you can just throw an exception, and tell user how many kinds of `Food`s exist.

Comment: @Don So I dont know which implementations exist, but loading at runtime would be too much. Enough for them to compile the program with all implementations, and then at runtime choose which.

Comment: @HiwayChe I think factory pattern will only work if I know which implementations exists.

Comment: @Juan, yes, do you have any implementations that do not exist? create them on the fly?

Comment: Not on the fly, but for every new implementation done I dont want to have to go back to my factory and change it. Yes, better than changing the main file, and adding ifs/new type statements, but not the idea either. Implementations do not have to be done all today, tomorrow or this month, maybe someone decide to do "picnic" in a year from now.

Comment: @Juan, you can have a xml file to store the `Food` nick name and `Food implementation` class name, when you get nick name, you can use reflection to create a new instance. So when a new implementation added, you just change xml file, no need change code.

Comment: @HiwayChe that is a really good proposal, I will try both this and one of the other answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds to me like the Strategy Pattern will suite your needs  (GOF - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

I am unclear just how dynamic you want this to be. Having two implementations of an interface, and a selector method to pick between is simplest. But you can also go as far as dynamically generating the implementation of the interface on the fly, which would probably be over kill for you here. Either way the strategy pattern can abstract this kind of complexity and give you the ability to select different behaviours based on any runtime criteria that you want.

Here is an example of loading a class dynamically, assuming that you already know the fully qualified class name and that the object has a no arg constructor:

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.Object");
Object o = c.newInstance();

System.out.println( "o = " + o );
```

The errors that you will need to catch for this case are: InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException; quite a few but just handle them all in the same way and reject the users selection.

If you need a constructor with arguments then:

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
Constructor cons = c.getConstructor( String.class ); // the args here are the expected types for the constructor that you require on the class
String s = (String) cons.newInstance( "hello" );
```

This will add even more exceptions that will have to be caught: InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException. But again just reject the users selection in the same way as before.

Comment: I wouldnt know the implementation class names, so someone could create "dinner" or "secondBreakfast". Which would lead me to another dilema, what to do if user selects a "class" that is not implemented yet :S

Comment: What is your 'discovery' criteria for capturing what the user wants? Based on that you can use reflection to load a class dynamically at runtime. If no such class exists then the users criteria is invalid and that case has to be handled.

Comment: atm I am thinking of user running the application with the class name as argument.So for my understanding, I would have the interface and then instead of loading all implementation, I would only load the class which makes the argument? Sadly I am used to using IDEs, so I normally leave loading to be automated.

Comment: Okay, no problem. editing answer above to give an example of loading the class dynamically via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the class names and want to know all classes available, you need to get all implementations of your interface at runtime.
This can be achieved with Reflections : http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Have a look at the Method `getSubTypesOf`

If you want the user to provide it's own implementation and use this one, you have different options :

1) Read the provided Jar at startup and use Dependency Injection with a pre configured Setup (e.g. with Spring). The user can write the fully qialified classname into the setup before the application is started.

2) Use a Plugin-Mechanism, like ServiceLoader : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html or JSPF : http://code.google.com/p/jspf/.

Or if you want to read new implementations at runtime you could use OSGi : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi (Have a look at Apache Karaf, Eclipse Equinox and Apache Felix).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be exactly describing Java's `interface`.  For example:

Food.java:

```
interface Food {
    void makeFood();
}
```

Breakfast.java:

```
class Breakfast implements Food {
    void makeFood() { System.out.println("Breakfast."); }
}
```

Lunch.java:

```
class Lunch implements Food {
    void makeFood() { System.out.println("Lunch."); }
}
```

Here we have two different implementations of `Food`, as you said.  Now, we can instantiate a `Food` object by constructing either of the implementing classes:

```
Food myFood = new Breakfast();
```

or

```
Food myFood = new Lunch();
```

There is no deleting of files or anything like that.  Hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Yes, so thats the interace idea. The problem is this:
Food myFood = new X(); /let x be define at runtime by user.
I could do if(arg = lunch) new Food = new Lunch(), but what happens if someone decides to implement dinner? Then I have to rewrite the code.

Comment: Who do you mean by 'user', and how will they be interacting with the system? One can use reflection to dynamically detect and instantiate classes at run time.

Comment: I generate the main file, and the interface. A second person can generate implementations of the interface and a user would be who ever compiles the main, the interface, and all available implementations and then runs program and inputs the implementation type "breakfast", "lunch" or X named.